# Set environmental vars and enable core dumps in autotools build

Tags: linux, path, autotools

I am using Autotools for my current project. I'm using Ubuntu and Linux mint. With Autotools I can tell it to check a users's system to check for any required libraries my project needs in order to function properly. Now I would like to check if a user's system has enabled core dumps and if not, then execute the command `ulimit -c unlimited` to enable core dumps. How and where do I specify this?

Also, once the user has executed the make command to compile the source code, they execute `sudo make install` in order to move the binaries at `/usr/local/bin/MYPROJECT`. I want to add the location of my project's binaries into the path environmental variable, so that the user can execute any of the binaries in my project from a terminal without the need of typing the full path. How and where do I specify this in Autotools?

I'm thinking this is something I would add in the configure.ac file, but I haven't found any examples on how I can do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you basically misunderstand what installation of a software 
package on Linux is about.

The job of autotools is to build a portable installation package of your
software. When I install your package, it does not become *your* decision
whether programs that crash will generate core dumps on *my* computer
when I run them. It does not become *your* decision what `PATH` I use to
invoke programs by unqualified name. These are *my* decisions or defaults
that I have accepted from my OS distribution.

If you execute `ulimit -c unlimited`, the command will in any case
only apply to the shell in which it is invoked. It doesn't
reconfigure the host system (!).

If you would like users to be able to invoke your program by unqualified
name, the normal procedure is make your package install it by default in the place,
`/usr/local/bin`, that unix-like OSes traditionally add to a
user's default `PATH` for finding locally installed programs. That is
where autotools will configure it to be installed, by default. Change it
only if you *don't* want your program to be in the user's default `PATH`.

And in any case, a user can decide where your software is installed by
passing `--prefix=/path/of/my/choice` to the `./configure` command. Unless
you have some *unavoidable* reason not to, make your package installation
use the defaults that everybody expects and leave it up to the installing user
to change them.

Bottom line: You are asking how to do installation actions with autotools that
are not meant to be done with autotools, because they are not meant to be
done by package installations.

Comment: You are absolutely right my friend. After reading your comment, I realized that what I was trying to do is NOT the right way of doing things. Thank you for steering me in the right direction!